# PostgreSQL Container in Docker Not Authorizing a Correct Password

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, relational-database

I have arranged a node.js back end to connect to a redis cache and psql database.

The app I have created is running but I would like to do some database admin and have attempted to log in using pgAdmin - however, my details were rejected.

I thought it might be a pgAdmin thing so I attempted to use the login URI in powershell but again it was rejected.

I checked that the psql service is running on the exposed port (in case I messed up the docker-compose config) and it is...not sure where to go from here.

My docker-compose config for the database is:

```
# PostgreSQL
postgres:
container_name: postgres
build: ./postgres
environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    POSTGRES_URL: postgres://admin:password@localhost:5432/myapp
    POSTGRES_DB: myapp
    POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

I should note that the database is running - I can log in to my front end and access data, etc...

My login attempt:

```
psql postgres://admin:password@localhost:5432/myapp
```

And the response:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you docker-compose not formatted well if it's not copy-paste issue as the environment variable, not place properly.

```
# PostgreSQL
postgres:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    POSTGRES_URL: postgres://admin:password@localhost:5432/myapp
    POSTGRES_DB: myapp
    POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

Or you can try

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  postgresdb:
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: appdb
      POSTGRES_USER: appdb 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123123
    image: bitnami/postgresql:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Or better to post you Dockerfile, as I see your building your own Docker image, but better to use the offical image of Postgres like the one I posted above.

Also will suggest debugging on container DB first and verify connectivity on the container localhost, debugging and testing with depended containers like connecting from nodejs first here one lost in the actual problem.

Check if your ENV set properly.

```
docker exec postgres bash -c "printenv "
```

or

```
 docker exec postgres bash -c "printenv | grep POSTGRES_"
```

or

```
docker exec -it postgres bash -c "psql -U admin myapp"
```